# How to convert JavaScript(UnityScript) to C# and implement a low pass filter?

Tags: javascript, c#, unityscript, lowpass-filter

I've been trying to implement a low-pass filter code sample that I found In the Unity Manual into my game but I am having some issues.

Here is the original JavaScript sample found in the Unity Manual:

```
var AccelerometerUpdateInterval : float = 1.0 / 60.0;
var LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds : float = 1.0;

private var LowPassFilterFactor : float = AccelerometerUpdateInterval /    LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds; // tweakable
private var lowPassValue : Vector3 = Vector3.zero;

function Start () 
{
    lowPassValue = Input.acceleration;
}

function LowPassFilterAccelerometer() : Vector3 
{
    lowPassValue = Mathf.Lerp(lowPassValue, Input.acceleration, LowPassFilterFactor);
    return lowPassValue;
}
```

Here is my conversion to C#:

```
float AccelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0f / 60.0f;
float LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds = 1.0f;

private float LowPassFilterFactor = AccelerometerUpdateInterval / LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds; // tweakable
private Vector3 lowPassValue = Vector3.zero;

void  Start ()
{
    lowPassValue = Input.acceleration;
}

Vector3 LowPassFilterAccelerometer ()
{
    lowPassValue = Mathf.Lerp(lowPassValue, Input.acceleration, LowPassFilterFactor);
    return lowPassValue;
}
```

My original code to move my character using the accelerometer was this(no low pass filter):

```
float speed = 30.0f;
Vector2 dir;
private float accel;

void Start () 
{
    accel = Input.acceleration.x;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{  
    accel = Mathf.MoveTowards (accel, Input.acceleration.x, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    dir = new Vector3(accel, 0);

    // move the object at the velocity defined in speed:
    transform.Translate(dir * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

This is my attempt to implement the low pass filter to reduce the noise/jerkiness:

```
float AccelerometerUpdateInterval = 1.0f / 60.0f;
float LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds = 1.0f;

private float LowPassFilterFactor;
private Vector3 lowPassValue = Vector3.zero;

public float speed = 30.0f;

void Start () 
{
    lowPassValue = Input.acceleration;
    LowPassFilterFactor = AccelerometerUpdateInterval / LowPassKernelWidthInSeconds; 
}

Vector3 LowPassFilterAccelerometer() 
{
    lowPassValue = Mathf.Lerp(lowPassValue, Input.acceleration, LowPassFilterFactor);
    return lowPassValue;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{  
    // move the object at the velocity defined in speed:
    transform.Translate(LowPassFilterAccelerometer() * speed * Time.deltaTime, 0);
}
```

I am getting some errors when I try to compile the script:

> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   `UnityEngine.Mathf.Lerp(float, float, float)' has some invalid
>   arguments
>
> error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert`UnityEngine.Vector3'
>   expression to type `float'

Comment: I think error messages are clear. Have you ever read them? Clearly the parameters types are wrong one of `Lerp` method that you used. For the second one, you try to cast `Vector3` type to `float` which seems not possible.

Comment: It says that Mathf.Lerp only takes float arguments .. but why would the sample from the Unity Manual use Vector3's ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example code may be wrong.  Use  [`Vector3.Lerp()`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html) instead.  A full list of Lerps is [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=lerp).

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you all you need to know. Look at the signature for `UnityEngine.Mathf.Lerp(float, float, float)`

One of the parameters you're passing to it isn't a `float`.

Comment: Yeah I realize that but why would the manual use Vector3's? http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MobileInput.html

Comment: @LooMeenin - Maybe the example in the documentation is wrong?  There's also [`Vector3.Lerp`](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html).  More [here](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/30_search.html?q=lerp).

Comment: @dbc: That's quite possible, yes.